# Как сделать вывод ECHO без номеров строк?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Есть несколько SQL и PL/SQL скриптов, которые запускаются вместе в пакете через SQL*Plus.

Я устанавливаю `SET ECHO OFF` и `SET ECHO ON` в нужных местах скриптов для вывода запускаемого кода.

В настоящее время вывод выглядит примерно так:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      ct number := 0;
  3      ctChanges number := 0;
  4  BEGIN
  5      select count(*) into ct
  6      from dual;
  7      /* rest of code block... */
  8      dbms_output.put_line ('some specific message');
  9  END;
 10  /
some specific message

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Этот вывод  сохраняется как лог выполнения и позднее можно получить доступ к нему в виде текстового файла.

Однако, недостатком этого формата вывода является то, что если скопировать определенный участок кода для того, чтобы запустить его снова, например, в SQL*Plus или SQL Developer, то надо сначала в редактире убрать номера строк.

Возможно ли установить в SQL*Plus, чтобы он выводил код, как показано выше, **но без номеров строк**?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle SQLPlus: Echo without line numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59210786) от участника [@Kjartan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336648/kjartan)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/59210786

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользиваться системными переменными [SQLNUMBER, SQLPROMPT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-A6A5ADFF-4119-4BA4-A13E-BC8D29166FAE)

```
set sqlprompt ''
set sqlnumber off
```

> SQLN[UMBER] {ON | OFF}
>
> Sets the prompt for the second and subsequent lines of a SQL command or PL/SQL block.
> `ON` sets the prompt to be the line number.
> `OFF` sets the prompt to the value of `SQLPROMPT`.

Вывод будет выглядеть вот так:

```
DECLARE
    ct number := 0;
    ctChanges number := 0;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into ct
    from dual;
    /* rest of code block... */
    dbms_output.put_line ('some specific message');
END;
/
some specific message

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59210897) от участника [@GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb)</sub>